# PostgreSQL points to line error

Tags: postgresql, sql, json, st-makeline

I have GPS locations with date. These are points.

I want to convert the points to lines, sorted by date.

Using PostgreSQL

Tried:

```
SELECT observations.id,
       ST_MakeLine(observations.geom ORDER BY observations.date) AS newgeom
FROM   observations 
GROUP BY
       observations.id
;
```

The problem is that the single line values gives the same coordinates. So, there will be no line. 0 and 1 are the same.

[image]

How is this possible?

Comment: order by geom first then by date > http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2017/09/postgis-operators.html   'ST_MakeLine(observations.geom ORDER BY observations.geom) AS geom
FROM   observations 
GROUP BY
       observations.date'

Comment: @ Mapperz, this is not working. When i give: SELECT ST_MakeLine(observations.geom ORDER BY observations.geom) AS geom 
FROM observations 
GROUP BY observations.date; The problem is the same.